# Find full path of a powershell script launched from an EXE wrapper

Tags: windows, powershell, exe, filepath

I am trying to create an .exe file that is a packaged powershell script (script.ps1) in which part of the script is to print the current location of the **.exe file** NOT the Script.

Part of the Requirement is that the .exe needs to be portable:

So when I run File.exe or Double-click File.exe:

If the location of the file is **C:\Hello\File.exe** , it should print **"C:\Hello\"**

If the location is moved to **D:\Goodbye\File.exe** , it should print **"D:\Goodbye\"**

If the the file is COPIED to **D:\HELLO\File.exe** , it should ONLY print **"D:\HELLO\"**

---

I have tried `$PSScriptRoot` but that only links to a temp folder

---

What code can I add to the script.ps1 before packaging it as an .exe to make it look for the specific location of the **.exe** file?

Thanks

Comment: How are you creating the executable and how does it run the PowerShell script?

Comment: I am actually using a tool that compiles it called PS1ToExe ...   heres the link http://www.f2ko.de/en/p2e.php ... granted  I wish I understood how to do it otherwise ... but I am stuck on something basic like this lol

Comment: This is probably a bad idea. You say it has to be portable, but PowerShell runs on the .Net framework. If your target machine doesn't have .Net, it's not going to work. If it does have .Net, you don't need the .exe wrapper. Every version of Windows since Win 7/2008R2 comes with at least PowerShell 2.0 by default. What is the problem you're trying to solve by packaging the script in an .exe?

Comment: @briantist: Good points, but I think what the OP meant by "portable" in this case is merely the ability to place the executable in _any directory_ and have it work correctly. The `*.exe` wrappers generated by this tool allow invocation of the embedded PowerShell script irrespective of the effective PS security policy, so perhaps providing a simpler way to run the script is the motivation.

Comment: @mklement0 yeah could be, but the same could be achieved with a one line batch file that calls `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy`.

Comment: @briantist can you elaborate on the one line batch file? If the goal of part of my script was to make/edit a txt file in the same folder as the batch file, regardless of the location of the batchfile, would it be able to do so?

Comment: @AdilZia actually you can look at the example wrapper command posted in [mklement0's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40497180/3905079). That's a speculation of what the wrapper is doing (calling `powershell.exe`). If instead you put a line just like that in your batch file, to call your `.ps1`, then you can use `$PSScriptRoot` in your script. Within the batch file, you can use `%~f0\myScript.ps1` to refer to the file in the same path as the batch file I believe.

Comment: @briantist: Good advice, but it's `"%~dp0myScript.ps1"` (sic). The `*.exe` wrapper has one advantage over a batch file solution: it allows for a single, self-contained distribution and execution unit. Also, how the wrapper invokes PowerShell is not based on a guess, but actual experiments. As an aside: what is curious is that it doesn't use `-noprofile` or at least provide the option to specify it.

Comment: @mklement0 ah thanks, that looks right. I was going from memory and haven't done that in a while. Yeah full self containment is one advantage, but in my opinion not worth its drawbacks. I just find that usually when someone wants to do this they're trying to solve a perceived problem that isn't really one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tool you're using to wrap your PowerShell script in an `*.exe`, [Ps1 to Exe](http://www.f2ko.de/en/p2e.php), does the following when the `*.exe` is invoked:

- It extracts the embedded script to a temporary file in subtree `$env:TEMP`.
- It invokes the PowerShell *executable*, and passes it the path to the temporary script file via `-File`, along with `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass`.

Example command line invoked by a wrapper `*.exe`:

```
"powershell" -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Users\jdoe\AppData\Local\Temp\2409.tmp\240A.ps1
```

You therefore need to examine the *parent* process of the PowerShell instance running your script in order to obtain information about the *wrapper `*.exe`*.

```
# Get the parent process.
# (`gps` is a built-in alias of `Get-Process`)
$pp = gps -Id (Get-CimInstance win32_process -Filter "ProcessId = $PID").ParentProcessId

# Output the parent process executable's directory path:
Split-Path $pp.Path
```

Note: If you're still on PSv2, use `Get-WmiObject` instead of `Get-CimInstance`.

Comment: Hey, So My Script is INSIDE the exe package, Do I do JUST the second half, or the top PLUS the second half?

Comment: It's either one OR the other; based on your comment on Jonathan's answer, it sounds like the _first_ snippet is what you need.

Comment: Thanks, thats also giving me the temp folder when the exe is run lol

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Sorry. I am a Beginner at Powershell and system side stuff. All I do after compiling the the ps1 to exe with this tool http://www.f2ko.de/en/p2e.php... I just double-click or run the EXE file

Comment: @AdilZia: Please see my update, but my recommendation hasn't changed: you need to obtain the wrapper executable's directory path from the _parent_ process.

Answer (score 4):

I've never worked with packaged PowerShell scripts, but if the PowerShell engine is being hosted by the EXE packaging the script, then something like this should do the trick:

```
$FullPathToEXE = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName

$DirectoryContainingEXE = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($FullPathToEXE)
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately just like $PSScriptRoot, it still points to the temp folder

Comment: Ah, shucks. :-)

Comment: In the absence of specific information, it was worth a shot :) Note that a pure PowerShell translation of your command is much more terse (though probably slower): `$DirectoryContainingExe = Split-Path (Get-Process -ID $PID).Path`.

Comment: Huh, fascinating. PowerShell's `Get-Process` returns a `System.Diagnostics.Process` object, pretty much directly, and `Process` does not have a `Path` property. But, `types.ps1xml` in `%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` contains a specific mapping for the `System.Diagnostics.Process` type that adds a whole bunch of extra "virtual" properties. `Path` is one of them:

      `<ScriptProperty>
        <Name>Path</Name>
        <GetScriptBlock>$this.Mainmodule.FileName</GetScriptBlock>
      </ScriptProperty>`

Comment: Excellent sleuthing. A more immediate way to inspect this property is to use `(Get-Process -id $PID) | Get-Member Path`.

Comment: .... Lol I wish what I understood what you guys were talking about. here..... sigh

Comment: @AdilZia PowerShell is a language like C# or VB.NET that exposes .NET objects. But, PowerShell is designed for extensibility. Part of that extensibility is that you can actually "add" new members to types, usually by either forwarding to another property or making them secretly execute a block of PowerShell script. I learned this fact as part of this StackOverflow question. So, in this case, I was surprised when I saw that you could access `.Path` on a `Process` object directly -- an object that doesn't *have* a property called `.Path`. I set out to figure out how exactly that works. :-)